# JavaScript loading concept

Tags: javascript, html-parsing

How does browser load javascript? In an HTML page we have code written inside `<script>` tag and also JS downloaded using `<script src=""/>` tag. Does browser download the JS asynchronously in the second case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the scripts get downloaded asynchronously, but executed in order

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply.So if I've a JavaScript function in one of the script files, does browser parses each and every line of that function. OR it will parse it only when that function is called? Could you please suggest some online reference of JavaScript loading concepts.

Comment: http://w3schools.com/js/default.asp is a great place to start learning - and you can use http://jsfiddle.net/ to test your code and send snippets for other people to look at

Comment: from my experience, the browser parses all the javascript documents, and if there is a syntax error, it skips all javascript in that file. It then executes all javascript in order that it is written in the source, so if you include a script file, you can safely call it's functions from any subsequent javascript files or inline scripts. The functions are loaded when the browser parses, but executed only when you call them. Maybe someone can point to a good online resource to explain better... anyone..?